# Material-UI AppBar click is not working in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying some things in react. I'm rendering the **AppBar** and the **Drawer** from **v0 Material-UI** as **functional components**. I have added the **handleDrawerClick** function in the class and sending the **function as a props** to use as a click function in the functional component. But the click function is not working. The problem here is **wrapping up the function as the param and passing it as props might not be working**. If there's any other way to achieve the click **any help would be appreciated** but we need to make sure that we're using the fancy components in the functional components and rendering those in the class just like shown in the Demo. **onLeftIconButtonClick, the drawer open and closing needs to get controlled**.

I have added one working demo here through **stackblitz** => [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6npk2v?embed=1&file=index.js)

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import './style.css';

export const getMenuBar = (isBarOpened) => {
  return(
    <Drawer open={isBarOpened}>
      <MenuItem>Menu Item</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
    </Drawer>
  );
}

export const getAppBar = (handleDrawerClick) => {
  return(
    <AppBar 
      title="My AppBar" 
      className="st_appBarClass" 
      titleStyle={{ color: "#FFFFFF" }}
      onLeftIconButtonClick={handleDrawerClick()}
    />
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
      isMenuOpened: false
    };
  }

  handleDrawerClick = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    if(e) {
      this.setState({ isMenuOpened: !this.state.isMenuOpened });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
        <div className='product-list-wrapper'>
          {/*<ProductList products={products} />*/}
          {getAppBar(this.handleDrawerClick)}
          {getMenuBar(this.state.isMenuOpened)}
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: According to the `<AppBar /> API` of Material UI, there is no `onLeftIconButtonClick` props.

Comment: @zynkn It's there. Please check the link => **https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar**

Comment: Are you using `v0` of material UI?

Comment: @zynkn yes, I'm using `v0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const getAppBar = (handleDrawerClick) => {
  return(
    <AppBar 
      title="My AppBar" 
      className="st_appBarClass" 
      titleStyle={{ color: "#FFFFFF" }}
      onLeftIconButtonClick={handleDrawerClick} //Remove ()
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**To open menu** remove unnecessary round brackets

```js
<AppBar 
      title="My AppBar" 
      className="st_appBarClass" 
      titleStyle={{ color: "#FFFFFF" }}
      onLeftIconButtonClick={handleDrawerClick}//<---here
    />
```

**To close menu** provide an onClick to the parent div

```js
<div onClick={this.handleDrawerClick} className='product-list-wrapper'> //<----here
          {/*<ProductList products={products} />*/}
          {getAppBar(this.handleDrawerClick)}
          {getMenuBar(this.state.isMenuOpened)}
        </div>
```